The problem with hysteresis is in the comparator circuit with a mosfet. Oscillations during switching
In one of the design guides, I came across a circuit of a comparator with hysteresis. I modeled it in LTspice and built the circuit as shown in the figure.

However, when I tested it with real components, I encountered parasitic fluctuations in the switching process. I'm not sure what could be the reason for these fluctuations. Are there any limitations to this circuit?


You're better off using purpose-designed comparators instead of op amps if you're really concerned about transient behaviors.

However, is this normal behavior for such a circuit?

Besides using an opamp instead of a comparator, what is the purpose of M1?

Introduce hysteresis into the circuit to prevent noise.

@Typeofundefined That's not how you would do this. The transistor and one of the resistors is unnecessary.

@MOSFET What’s wrong with it, since it adjusts voltage divider and shifts switch voltage level as ordinary comparator with hysteresis, but this also isolates inputs from output to eliminate loading effect on reference source through feedback resistor? Also such functional scheme often showed in pvd’s and other ic’s which exhibit hysteresis.

@MakePlatanGreatAgain That MOSFET isn't isolating anything. Ironically, it's actually adding capacitive loading to your op amp which is in direct conflict to comparator requirements; a bipolar would be better here. And just to be clear, I said some parts were unnecessary; not technically wrong. Sure, you could make this opamp comparator scheme work with lower performance than a proper design. But why would you want to? What value does the MOSFET even add? And 99.9% of the time you don't want to use an opamp as comparator. So why is your design part of the 0.1%?

@MOSFET yes it adds loading as Ciss and Coss, but by isolating as I said in previous comment it really lowers current flow from feedback to reference source and since source has finite resistance it lowers voltage offset on one of the inputs. I guess that part selection might be shortage on parts. Op amps which can drive capacitive load and have high slew rate could work here.

@MakePlatanGreatAgain You're not understanding. The dominant loading comes from Cgs - it's the gate capacitance that the amplifier has to drive. And you want this to happen quickly to make a good comparator. Also, elaborate on this "isolating current flow from feedback to reference source". Your transistor doesn't affect the reference (2.495V) at all.

@MOSFET Yes, transistor doesn’t affect the reference, that’s because it is placed here. Basic schemes which use feedback resistor making current flow from output to one of the inputs and shifting voltage on that node. Coss can be neglected? So what will happen when MOSFET gate will be charged at Vgsth and current through divider will be still more than transistor can handle?

@MakePlatanGreatAgain You lost me. Earlier comment "...this [transistor] also isolates inputs from output to eliminate loading effect on reference source.." The reference would be isolated with or without the transistor - it's connected to a high-Z input of your amplifier. And this part "So what will happen when MOSFET gate will be charged at Vgsth and current through divider will be still more than transistor can handle?" You use a transistor that can handle the divider current? I would imagine you would spec a transistor that is sized for the current.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The oscillations are due to the parasitic capacitances of the MOSFET M1, Cgs and Cgs, as follows:-

Cgs delays the turn-on and turn-off of M1, which slows the arrival positive feedback signal (from the op-amp output to the positive feedback node).
Cds provides negative feedback directly from op-amp output to the op-amp negative input via R2.


Solutions:
Solution #1
Choose a MOSFET with smaller parasitics.  The datasheet of the MOSFET you used (IRLML6344) shows these to be significant, between 200pF & 800pF, refer image below.

Link for the image above:
https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/n-channel/irlml6344/
You don't need such a heavy current MOSFET in this application;  a MOSFET with a higher Rds(ON) would be suitable and have far smaller parasitic capacitance.  For example, BSS134, Rds(ON)=3.5Ω, but Ciss and Crss are between 2pF and 50pF (hundreds of times smaller).

Link for the image above:
https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/small-signal-small-power/bss138w/
Solution #2
Add AC positive feedback directly to the op-amp.  Refer image below:

Add R4 & C1.  Select this time-constant as follows:

Longer than the delay due to M1;
Shorter than the maximum switching rate of output.

Add R5 to assist the opamp, and prevent M1 Cgs from slowing down the positive feedback via C1 & R4.

Per the discussion, why doesn't this work:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
U1 is a rail-to-rail comparator. Not an amplifier.
Obviously, you need to adjust the resistor values to set the scaling and hysteresis loop.

I am not happy with this circuit because the hysteresis depends on the output voltage of the comparator.

@Typeofundefined That's true. But I was assuming the 5V was constant. You need this circuit to work with a varying comparator supply voltage? So that the transitions are independent of supply voltage? Over what range will the supply voltage vary?

From 4.5 to 5.5 volts. Reference source calibrated to 1% accuracy

@Typeofundefined so your issue isn't the comparator. Your issue is with a varying voltage supply. I've updated the schematic.

I meant that the supply voltage is not regulated, that is, it can vary depending on the tolerance of the components. @mosfet
